# using coalesce to set initial value of variable in query

Tags: mysql

Excuse me if this has already been asked, but searching for coalesce brings up a bunch of results that don't help me ...

In mysql, I'm trying to use coalesce to set an initial value for a variable that is set with an expression that depends on the existing value. I'd really like to do it with one statement, but I'm having a problem where the value that comes back from coalesce when the variable is null doesn't seem to "stick" and I get the initial value every time. The weird thing, if I set the variable initially to null, it works as expected.

Consider this query:

```
select @y := coalesce(@y+1, 5)
from table
limit 5;
```

It returns:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

But this:

```
set @z = null;
select @z := coalesce(@z+1, 5)
from table
limit 5;
```

Returns what I expect:

```
5
6
7
8
9
```

Is this a bug or expected behavior? Is the solution to just initially set the variable to null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize the SQL Variables in a "( select ... ) alias " reference as below.  You just need to make sure you alias it such as I've done as SQLVars otherwise it will choke on you.  Then you can build as many as you need of whatever data types.

```
select
      @z := z+1 as NextNumber
   from table,
      ( select @z := 5, 
               @AnotherVar := 'First Value',
               @AnythingElse := 390.290 ) SQLVars   
  limit 5;
```